# Which database is the most space efficient

Tags: database, oracle

Current we are using Oracle to store logging information. One of the column is a blob that stores an XML payload. We archive the logging schema every week, but we still hit about > 1TB a week.

Goal: Reduce space footprint of database

Solution 1:
Compress the XML payload before putting it into the BLOB.

Solution 2:
Look for a database (noSQL or other relational DB) that already compresses data on default. JDBC driver must be available.

Anyone know a database that fits into solution 2? So that we do not need to modify the app, we just need to change the DB and update the JDBC drivers.

Comment: An inbetween solution might be to use the UTL_COMPRESS oracle package to compress/uncompress the blobs as you insert/retrieve the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle supports a few different levels of compression - that fits in to solution 2 with minimal effort. (Table / row / lob compression)

Comment: sorry to hijack the question but from what version?

Comment: Prior to 11g, Oracle's table compression was suitable for data warehouses, but was perhaps not efficient enough for OLTP applications.  Even in 11g it costs additional CPU cycles, so be sure to benchmark before you put it into production.

Comment: However, I think using UTL_COMPRESS to squish the XML payload will fit the bill nicely.

Answer (score 0):

All the dbms that I know of that support both compression and JDBC.

- Oracle
- SQL Server
- DB2
- Teradata

PostgreSQL relies on the underlying operating system for storage. You could probably build PostgreSQL tablespaces on a compressed filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would say if you have enterprise, then partition that xml table and periodically backup and prune it (if partitioned by date range, then remove partitions older than x).  If that isn't an option, you may try a noSQL data store.

There are plenty of noSQL options available.  One I've played with (not yet production) is [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).  It stores the data in a binary JSON format (BSON), and can be compressed.  It seems to be making headway with [bigger companies](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments) as well.  I once worked on a similar b-tree flat file system some time ago, was very fast.  You won't have the same features as a RDBMS though.  Good thing about mongoDB is that its commercially supported by 10gen (again, can't say how good that support is, but that's important to some shops).

Here's a good [article](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis) discussing the pros/cons of the bigger noSQL options out there.

And no, I don't work for 10gen ;)  Of course do more research and decide what's best for your needs

Comment: Partitioning is an *additional cost option*.  It does not come free with Enterprise Edition.

Comment: MongoDB stores schema with every document. That is huge space wasting.